# C program return 1 if x > 0, 0 if x = 0, or -1 x < 0

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

i need to write a program that will return 1 if x > 0, 0 if x = 0, or -1, if x < 0 in C using only bitwise operators.

Edit: sorry for any confusion since bitwise is what the prompt says but these are the valid operators.
! ~ & ^ | + << >> and parentheses

currently i have tried this

```
int positive = ((x >> 31) & 1);
int negative = !((x >> 31) & -1);
int zero = !x;
return positive | !zero | ~negative;
```

but it fails to return -1 properly and instead returns it when the number is positive and I am confused. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Remember that `-1` has the hex value `0xFFFFFFFF`.  So, `& -1` with a 32-bit value does not change the value at all.

Comment: Right shift on negative integer results in an implementation defined value. In other words, using `>>` isn't portable.

Comment: Further... The type of `x` isn't mentioned in the question so we can't even be sure that bit 31 is a sign bit. So additional information is needed. In general it is (AFAIK) impossible to write portable code if you only are allowed to use bitwise operators.

Comment: This task is senseless. Notably, `=` is not a bitwise operator, neither is `-` or `!` or `()`. Why are you using operators which are not bitwise?

Comment: `-` in this code is just part of a literal, and `=()` are just nitpicking, but I agree with `!`.

Comment: @WeijunZhou There is no such thing as "`-` is part of a literal" in C. The C language does not support negative literals.

Comment: This is: the question is unclear unless you clearly specify exactly which operators you are allowed to use. Relaxing requirements at a whim/as you go is a strange approach - either you have a requirement or you don't. The bitwise operators are `& | ~ ^ >> <<` and their compound assignment equivalents.

Comment: That the `-` in `-1` is not part of a literal in the C standard is something TIL, I stand corrected.

Comment: Now this is really starting to look like a popularity-contest on [codegolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

edit:

```
return (x >> 31) | !!x;
```

Comment: `-` is not a bitwise operator.

Comment: @WeijunZhou Thanks for mentioning that. I just updated the answer.

Comment: Neither is `!` if we are to be pedantic.

Comment: @Lundin Yes if we are strict on "bitwise operator". I'm trying to come up with a better one : )

Comment: Unless the OP can clarify their requirements, the question is senseless. I'm not sure if it is even possible to write this without using either `()` or `,` operator.

Comment: Without running, would this not return `1` for a negative input, against the OP's requirements?

Comment: This ended up working. it seems i was confused about the >> operator since it copies the sign bit instead of just replacing with zero

Comment: @ChandlerDotson Good to know it helped : )   >> is arithmetic shift (keeps the sign bit) when you are shifting a signed value.

Comment: @Rogue (x >> 31) gives -1 and (!!x) gives 1 for negative inputs. The result is -1 | 1 = -1.

Comment: @Qing yup, I forgot about `>>` filling with the leftmost bit instead of 0s.

Answer (score 3):

> using only bitwise operators

That's a nonsense requirement really - particularly it doesn't make sense to write such a program without assignment, parenthesis or logical operators... but if those are the requirements, then:

- The bitwise operators are `& | ~ ^ >> <<` and their compound assignment equivalents.
- `-` is not a bitwise operator.
- `!` is not a bitwise operator.
- `=` is not a bitwise operator.
- `()` (parenthesis and/or cast) is not a bitwise operator.

Therefore the code that actually fulfills the requirements needs to be something artificial and obscure such as this:

```
int x; // given some value earlier

static int neg;
neg |= x&1u<<31;
neg >>= 31; // assuming arithemtic shift

static _Bool pos;
pos |= x & 0x7FFFFFFF;
pos &= ~neg;

return neg | pos;
```

(Apart from assuming arithmetic shift, this also assumes two's complement signed representation.)

Comment: I'd argue that `|=` is actually not (only) a bitwise operator because of its assignment part. But I understand that one might say it is, particularly in the light of this question ;-).

Comment: I upvoted. Note that this also makes assumptions about `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: This makes all manner of strange non-portable assumptions indeed - it's essentially code golf/a coding puzzle.

Comment: The code assumes 32-bit `int` and `_Bool` and boolean type support, in addition to 2's complement.

Comment: Since you assume arithmetic shift, why bother with `neg |= x&1u<<31;` and not write `neg |= x`, or even `neg |= x >> 31` and `pos |= x`

Comment: @chqrlie Boolean type support has been in the C language for almost 25 years now - you would have to visit museum in order to find a compiler without it. As for the `neg |= x`, the requirement was to return `-1` in case of negative, not just return a negative value. This is silly code no matter - an artificial answer to suite artificial requirements.

Comment: I meant `neg |= x;` and your `neg >>= 31;` or just `neg |= x >> 31;` which combines both.  Boolean type is indeed supported since C99, but boolean conversion is arguably not a bitwise operator.  I posted an alternative solution that does not use intermediary variables.

Answer (score 2):

If you can assume these:

- two's complement representation (now mandated by C23)
- arithmetic right shift (shifting a negative value replicates the sign bit)
- 32-bit int

Right shifting `x` by `31` produces `-1` if `x` is negative and `0` if `x` is positive or zero.

Cumulating all value bits into the low order bit can be done iteratively.

Here is a solution as a function:

```
int sign(int x) {
    x |= x >> 16;
    x |= x >> 8;
    x |= x >> 4;
    x |= x >> 2;
    x |= x >> 1;
    return (x >> 31) | (x & 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether that would be considered cheating but you can simply exploit the implicit evaluation of integers as booleans in C's control structures. That is, you can simply branch depending on whether the sign bit is set. After all, `if()` and `return` are not operators. (To produce the proper return value *in a single expression* would be much harder.)

Below is my program, and [here is a version on godbolt](https://www.godbolt.org/z/Pzzfxcb9a).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

/** @return -1, 0 or 1 indicating whether n is 
    negative, 0 or positive, respectively, using only 
    a bitwise operator. Depends on 2's complement
    integer representation.
*/
static int is_neg_zero_or_pos(int n)
{
    // INT_MIN in 2's complement is only the sign bit. 
    // If the sign bit is set, number is < 0. 
    // Works for all int sizes.
    if (n & INT_MIN) { return -1; } 

    // Use implicit int -> bool conversion: true if not zero.
    // Would trigger for negative values, too, but we eliminated 
    // those above. 
    // Works for all int sizes.
    if (n) { return 1; }

    // Not != 0, must be 0.
    // Works for all int sizes as well ;-).
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    // a few test cases: zero (obviously), -1, 1, min and max int, 
    // and something arbitrary. We don't depend on 32 bit ints
    // but we do depend on 2's complement.
    printf("%d\n\n", is_neg_zero_or_pos(0));

    printf("%d\n", is_neg_zero_or_pos(1));
    printf("%d\n", is_neg_zero_or_pos(8543276));
    printf("%d\n\n", is_neg_zero_or_pos(INT_MAX));

    printf("%d\n", is_neg_zero_or_pos(-1));
    printf("%d\n", is_neg_zero_or_pos(-8543276));
    printf("%d\n", is_neg_zero_or_pos(INT_MIN));
}
```

Comment: `-` is not a bitwise operator. `()` function call is not a bitwise operator.

Comment: Are you referring to "-1"? That's formally correct but otherwise nitpicking because it is a language quirk, and trivially fixed. The function call, in case it wasn't obvious, is for test purposes. The relevant code is *within* is_neg_zero_or_pos. Well, I see -- relying on return implies a function call. Hm.

Comment: @Lundin I suppose this idea to use return cannot be salvaged then, bummer. (The equivalent expression would use ternary conditions but that's obviously not allowed).

Answer (score 1):

It is well possible that I missed the point by assuming you can branch and simply return -1 etc. in my other answer.

Here is a solution (in C++, but that doesn't matter) which constructs a value of 1, 0 or -1 in a single expression, using only bit operators. I made it readable by heavily using defines but you could write it out as well. (The defines assume a variable `n` which should really be its own macro parameter, but it's actually clearer this way, if we want to use that word here.)

The idea is to combine "bit spreading" and "bit conflating": The left subexpression "spreads" the sign bit over all bits in the number, resulting in either 0 or -1, depending on the sign. (I'm talking in signed terms although the parameter is unsigned; C and C++ convert automatically, preserving the bit pattern. I use unsigned because the shift operations are well defined there.)

The right subexpression "conflates" all bits into the least significant bit, resulting in either 0 or 1 depending on whether any bit was set (i.e., whether the number was not zero).

- ORing the two will not change the left -1 in case the number was negative.
- It will OR two zeroes if the number itself is zero, resulting in a zero result as desired.
- It will OR a zero and a 1 in case the number was true positive.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;

/// Get the Nth bit in n (lsb for N==0)
#define BIT(N) (n & (1 << N)) 

/// 1 if the Nth bit is set, else 0.
#define BITTOONE(N) (BIT(N) >> N)

/// OR the Nth bit, normalized to 1, with bit 0. 
/// If we do this for all bits, the expression is 1 if any bit was set.
#define BITTOONE_ORED(N) (BITTOONE(N) | BIT(0))

/// Shift the sign bit N places 
/// (note that N is not the bit index but the shift distance).
/// We are not allowed to subtract, but luckily 31 has 
/// no gap in its bits so that a subtraction amounts to simply 
/// deleting the subtrahend bits in 31.
#define SIGN_TO_N(N) (BIT(31) >> (31 & ~N))

/// Tricky: Do something for all bits from 0..31 and do something with the bit operation results.
/// A simple example is the DO_FOR_ALL_BITS(BIT, |) which simply re-ORs 
/// all the bits, resulting in the original number.
/// Basically an unrolled loop, since we cannot use decrement etc.
#define DO_FOR_ALL_BITS(op_with_bit, op_between) \
   (           (op_with_bit(0))  op_between (op_with_bit(1))  op_between (op_with_bit(2))  op_between (op_with_bit(3)) \
    op_between (op_with_bit(4))  op_between (op_with_bit(5))  op_between (op_with_bit(6))  op_between (op_with_bit(7))  \
    op_between (op_with_bit(8))  op_between (op_with_bit(9))  op_between (op_with_bit(10)) op_between (op_with_bit(11))  \
    op_between (op_with_bit(12)) op_between (op_with_bit(13)) op_between (op_with_bit(14)) op_between (op_with_bit(15))  \
    op_between (op_with_bit(16)) op_between (op_with_bit(17)) op_between (op_with_bit(18)) op_between (op_with_bit(19))  \
    op_between (op_with_bit(20)) op_between (op_with_bit(21)) op_between (op_with_bit(22)) op_between (op_with_bit(23))  \
    op_between (op_with_bit(24)) op_between (op_with_bit(25)) op_between (op_with_bit(26)) op_between (op_with_bit(27))  \
    op_between (op_with_bit(28)) op_between (op_with_bit(29)) op_between (op_with_bit(30)) op_between (op_with_bit(31))) 

int is_neg_zero_or_pos2(unsigned int n)
{
    return DO_FOR_ALL_BITS(SIGN_TO_N, | ) | DO_FOR_ALL_BITS(BITTOONE_ORED, | );
}

void testBitopsFunc(unsigned int n)
{
    int res = is_neg_zero_or_pos2(n);

    // n is unsigned. negative values of the argument 
    // are represented as values > INT_MAX since the sign bit is set.
    int expected = n > INT_MAX ? -1 : n > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    cout << "Expected:" << expected << ", returned: " << res << '\n';
    if (expected != res)
    {
        cout << "######## ERROR ########\n";
    }
}
int main()
{
    testBitopsFunc(0) ;
    testBitopsFunc(1) ;
    testBitopsFunc(2);
    testBitopsFunc(74326532);
    testBitopsFunc(INT_MAX);
    testBitopsFunc(-1);
    testBitopsFunc(-2);
    testBitopsFunc(-832547632);
    testBitopsFunc(INT_MIN);
}
```

A godbolt session is [here](https://www.godbolt.org/z/zr1T443Wj).

Comment: Reviewing the code I note that I use a subtraction to compute the shift distance in `SIGN_TO_N()`. Luckily we can substitute an easy bit operation for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
int posneg (int x) {
    return (((x + 0x7fffffff) >> 31) & 1) | (x >> 31);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    1.) Thank you for your update that the valid operators are ! ~ & ^ | + << >> and ().
    2.) You only really need help on determining positive and negative, so:
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Positive or Negative on a signed integer data type is determined by whether the 
** most significant bit is set (for negative) or not set (for positive). That's 
** what this macro checks. Successfully tested char, short, long, and long long(64bit) */
#define is_neg(a) (a >> ((sizeof(a)<<3)-1)  & 1)
/* NOTE: OP has updated question: the valid operators are ! ~ & ^ | + << >> and () */

int main()
{
    int x = -1;
    int positive = !is_neg(x);
    int negative = is_neg(x);

    if(positive)
        puts("POS");
    else 
        if(negative)
            puts("NEG");
    return 0;
}
```